# Update an existing SharePoint 2013 visual studio workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2012, update, custom-workflow

An article gave me the below steps to perform the update:

1. Change the workflow assembly's version number
2. Update the workflow assembly version number in the attribute of the Workflow element in    Workflow.xml file and the name attribute so that you can distinguish the new workflow from the    old workflow
3. Change the SolutionId in your manifest.xml file
4. Change the name of the .wsp solution package (i.e. CorpSite.Workflow.ITRequest.wsp to    CorpSite.Workflow.ITRequest.v1.1.wsp)
5. Deploy the new .wsp solution package
6. Run IISReset
7. Configure the old version of the workflow to disallow new instances of it from being created    by disabling all the start options in the old workflow association
8. Create a new workflow association using the new workflow that was just deployed

([Source](https://habaneroconsulting.com/Insights/Approach-to-upgrading-custom-SharePoint-workflows.aspx#.VaTYbPmqqko))

**According to the 2nd step**, I am unable to locate the attribute of workflow assembly version in the workflow.xml file.

Where is this property? Please Help!!

Comment: Isn't this instruction for Sharepoint 2010?